# curve fitting of Sigmoid function

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have a data

```
x           y
13.76568843 2.696647583
13.79385931 2.69759006
13.80765263 2.699298299
13.80765263 2.714868805
13.82125828 2.718167474
13.84792653 2.718835062
13.89921983 2.721191254
14.30468493 2.72821585
```

and I'd like to use Sigmoid function to fit this data set. The custom equation I use in matlab cftool is y(x) = B/(1+A*exp(-x))+C(A,B,C are constants). However, the matlab result is

```
A =   17.55
B =   6.531
C =   -3.819
```

The resulting fit curve is a sigmoid function curve (S shape)
However, it doesn't fit my data points locally at all. [To see the curve and my data points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD02S.jpg) (my data points are represented by red color)(And I have tried to set the limit of the constant A,B,C when doing the fitting, but it doesn't work)
[Zoom in to the fitting curve and my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlDDT.jpg)
I know I may improve this if I have enough data points. But this is all the data available at this moment. So I'm wondering if there is any way to do the curve fitting? not necessary to use matlab.Thank you!

Comment: You could try the Cruve Fitting Toolbox if you have it installed

Comment: @Airidas Korolkovas Yes, I do use a cftool in matlab

Comment: I have fitted your data with this function: B/(1+exp(-k*(x-x0)))+C

and obtained parameters B=0.02675, C=2.696, k=142.7, x0=13.81

Comment: @GuoZiwei As Airidas alluded to, you need to include a translation in `x`.

Comment: @edwinksl Yes, I know there should be a translation in x, so I include a parameter A. The translation will go into A, isn't it?

Comment: @GuoZiwei No, `A` scales `exp(-x)`, that's it. You additionally need `x-x0` like Aridas showed.

Comment: @ Airidas Korolkovas May I know which software you use? cftool in matlab? because I type the exactly the same function B/(1+exp(-k*(x-x0)))+C but get totally different parameter values...B = 4.34, C = -1.411, k= 0.199, x0 = -0.9249

Comment: I have used the cftool in Matlab. Since the fitting function is non-linear, it is important to provide parameter limits which are close to the anticipated solution. You need to constrain x0 between 13.7 and 13.9, and C between 2.6 and 2.8, which should be clear by looking at the data. The software should be then able to calculate more precise values for you

Comment: @Airidas Korolkovas Thank you so much! I have tried to set the limits before, but I guess the limits I set were not enough to constrain the fitting curve